"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" Error
I'm trying to implement a timer in my multiplayer Backgammon game.
export function startTurnTimer(gameId: string, color: "White" | "Black") {
  console.log(`startTurnTimer chiamato per gioco ${gameId}, giocatore: ${color}`);
  
  const gameData = games[gameId];
  if (!gameData) {
    console.error(`Gioco ${gameId} non trovato`);
    return;
  }
  const opponentColor = color === "White" ? "Black" : "White";
  
  // Cancella eventuali timer già attivi per evitare conflitti
  if (gameData.timers[color]) {
    console.log(`Cancello il timer precedente per ${color}`);
    clearInterval(gameData.timers[color]!);
    gameData.timers[color] = null;
  }
  
  // Avvia un nuovo timer
  gameData.timers[color] = setInterval(() => {
    const timeLeft = gameData.timeLeft[color];
  
    if (timeLeft > 0) {
      gameData.timeLeft[color] -= 1;
        
      // Emetti l'evento per aggiornare il client
      io.to(gameId).emit("updateTimer", {
        color,
        timeLeft: gameData.timeLeft[color],
      });
  
      console.log(`Tempo aggiornato per ${color}: ${gameData.timeLeft[color]}`);
    } else {
      gameData.timers[color] = null;
      celebrateGameEnd(gameData.thisTurn,io,gameId);
      console.log(`Chiamata a endGame per ${gameId} con vincitore ${opponentColor}`);
      endGame(gameId, opponentColor);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

This is the code that I use in my server to update the timers of my 2 players and update them by sending a io.to(gameId).emit("updateTimer", ...). I also have another emit in my code: io.to(gameId).emit("updateGameState", GameData) that I use to update the view of my clients and get them syncronized.
The problem is: If I call a io.to(gameId).emit("updateGameState", GameData) without the startTurnTimer executing I have no problems, but if I call it when the startTurnTimer is executing I have this error:

...\node_modules\socket.io-parser\build\cjs\is-binary.js:32
if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

What should I do?
I tried to implement it as above
